# Flutter - How to set textview height with image height and wrap it with 2 lines

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to Flutter and having problems in wrap text in the listing screen.

My current code is as follow:

```
Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(Dimen.padding),
                      color: AppTheme.buildLightTheme().backgroundColor,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              child:                                      
                                  Image.asset('assets/images/bike1.jpg',
                                      height: 80, width: 80, fit: BoxFit.cover)                                  
                              ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 16,
                          ),
                          Column(
                          verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Flexible(
                                  child: Text(
                                modelData.titleTxt,
                                style: (TextStyles.bldTextview),
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              )),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 6,
                              ),
                              Flexible(
                                  child: Text(modelData.subTxt,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: (TextStyles.regularTextview)))
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
```

**The output of this code is:**
[image: Current Output]

**What I want to achieve is like this:**
[image: Expected Output]

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In your expected output screenshot, each card has different value for `maxLines` based on the number of lines used by the title. But there is no attribute available in the current Text widget implementation of Flutter.

Well, you can workaround this by checking the available space using a `LayoutBuilder`, and based on available height, set the `maxLines` value.

See the below example.

```
 Container(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      width: 150.0,
      height: 110.0,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'I take up as much space as possible.',
            style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                  print(constraints);
              return Text(
                'The space I have is very limited. I get ellipsed.',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: (constraints.maxHeight / Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.fontSize).floor(),
              );
            }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: This code is not working with an image which shows the left side. The text view is going to disappear.

Comment: @DishaPatel  If you put the image and the Container i shown above in a row with fixed width for the image and Expanded width for the above container, it will work.

Comment: Can you able to send me that code which you have tested with row? and is max lines is also working according to title size?

Answer (score 0):

Just add **Expanded** widget in the column of title and subtitle.

```
Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(Dimen.padding),
                      color: AppTheme.buildLightTheme().backgroundColor,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            child: Image.asset('assets/images/bike1.jpg',
                                height: 80, width: 80, fit: BoxFit.cover),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 16,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  modelData.titleTxt,
                                  maxLines: 2,
                                  style: (TextStyles.bldTextview),
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 6,
                                ),
                                Text(modelData.subTxt,
                                    maxLines: 2,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: (TextStyles.regularTextview)),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
```